Raspberry Pi4 ARCH LINUX wifi fail brcmfmac issue
After the last update on RPI with ARCH LINUX OS: LINUX alarm 6.9.12-2-aarch64-ARCH I can not connection via  wifi. I get always in the terminal : brcmfmac: brcmf_set_channel: set chanspec 0x100e fail, reason -52 etc.
I googled and tried something for example set_power_safe_off but no success. How can I fix this brcmfmac issue?

Similar issue here, not just on the pi, my pinebook pro is also suffering from it. I tried looking at the history of the driver in the kernel but don't see any drastic changes in recent times.
For me, wifi networks without security still work, so I'm not sure if it is really the driver or something like networkmanager/wpa supplicant.
Were you able to verify with rolling back that it is indeed the kernel?
edit:
Quite a bit of talk on this issue, seems maybe wpa_supplicant related in combination with some kernel module thing
edit2:
I just tried out the fix in the aforementioned github issue and it works for me, what it comes down to is that some feature of the brcmfmac module must be disabled to fix it.
Temperorary method to test:
run
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac if this errors with module in use, try sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac-wcc brcmfmac, this unloads the brcmfmac module.
then run modprobe brcmfmac feature_disable=0x82000 this will disable some feature fixing the issue.
If this work you can make it permanent by making '/etc/modprobe.d/brcmfmac.conf' and filing it with: options brcmfmac feature_disable=0x82000
This will disable the feature when the module is loaded on startup.

Thanks for your help. I deleted brcmfmac but no success. To roll back with ARCH Linux to  the status before the issue is not possible only I go to an older iso. By the way when I set options in the brcmfmac.conf and reboot, the wlan0 no longer exists???

You deleted brcmfmac? I hope by that you mean remove, The fact that it doesn't load again worries me that you actually deleted it. Is there any message in dmesg about it failing to load with this option set?

yes I mean remove but I had a typo After reboot wlan0 is up, unfortunately I get the same error "brcmfmac.......................fail, reason -52"

I have now tested it with both my pinebook pro and my pi5 8gb, and it has fixed the issue on both, I don't know what else to say, besides double check the file name/location and the contents of it.
I feel like it would be strange if it works on pi5 but not pi4

it also worked on my pi3B

I will copy an older version of ARCH LINUX on my SD (where I know it works), than upgrade via pacman and then see what happens??? Nevertheless, thank you very much for your effort

In fact after roll back, upgrade to newest arch linux version and modeprobe.... it works. I can connect e.g. via ssh on the RPI. Great!!! The only problem I have now is every 10 sec a message in terminal "brcmf_p2p_send_action_frame: Unknown Frame: category 0x5, action 0x1" I guess this is a other story???

perhaps yeah, but good to hear you've got it working again.
